# I am loading a dataset in python,I tried with and without the comma and the result is the same. Can anyone explain its use?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am loading a json dataset and assigning it to variables. I tried using it with or without comma but the result is same. Can anyone explain me the significance of this commma here?

```
with open('datafile01.json', 'rb') as fa, open('datafile02.json', 'rb') as fb:
    policies, = json.load(fa).values()
    shifts, = json.load(fb).values()
```

Comment: Whenever you call `.values()` on a dictionary, you get a list of all the values. What is your underlying json file for reference?

Comment: Unpacking a sequence of length 1 ("with the comma") doesn't yield the same result as just binding it ("without the comma"). If you happen to get the same result with and without the comma, please post a full MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
a, = some_sequence
```

is a degenerate form of [sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), which only works for sequences of length 1 (else it raises a `ValueError` with either "too many values to unpack" or "need more than 0 values to unpack").

And this does NOT yield the same result as directly binding the sequence:

```
>>> d = {"x":1}
>>> a, = d.values()
>>> a
1
>>> a = d.values()
>>> a
dict_values([1])
>>>
```